# Swift Error: Function produces expected type '()'; did you mean to call it with '()'?

Tags: swift2

Don't know enough advanced Swift to figure out this error:

"Function produces expected type '()'; did you mean to call it with '()'?"

```
public func generate() -> AnyGenerator <(String, JSON)> {
    switch self.type {
    case .Array:
        let array_ = object as! [AnyObject]
        var generate_ = array_.generate()
        var index_: Int = 0
        return AnyGenerator<(String, JSON)> { <-- this is the line with the error
            if let element_: AnyObject = generate_.next() {
                return ("\(index_++)", JSON(element_))
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    case .Dictionary:
        let dictionary_ = object as! [String : AnyObject]
        var generate_ = dictionary_.generate()
        return AnyGenerator<(String, JSON)> {
            if let (key_: String, value_: AnyObject) = generate_.next() {
                return (key_, JSON(value_))
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    default:
        return AnyGenerator<(String, JSON)> {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the global function `anyGenerator` to initialize an `AnyGenerator` with a certain function. Also you can (have to) remove the generic parameters, because that's not allowed for functions and it gets infered anyways:

```
return anyGenerator {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @iphone007 What error do you get? I can't help you without any feedback